# Mark Dangle Error for linestring

Tags: python, postgis, pyqgis, postgresql, linestring

I will create buffer for 5 meter in start point of line string, If any other line string is within the buffer but not snapped then to mark as the startpoint as dangle error.I have attached the sample image given below, I don't want to get snapped element.

How to get it using PostGIS query?

[image: Line element start point is Snapped with other element]

Comment: I think you will need to provide more information as to how one might go about determining if a point is a dangle or not. Is there a timestamp, some other attribute, that could be used?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand your question, but it seems to me that if you tie the hanging lines to the main lines, it will solve your question, most likely you need the ST_Snap function: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html